# PL/SQL How to compare an expression in a trigger?

Tags: sql, plsql, triggers, oracle10g

I'm trying to output a message each time a student's new GPA is lower than their old GPA by 1 or more.

```
Create or Replace TRIGGER AUGPA
  after update on students
  for each row -- or should I put 'for GPA' the column name
begin
  if (:new.gpa - :old.gpa) >= 1 -- How do I compare these expressions? I get an error here. 
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('Old GPA is lower than previous GPA by at least 1 point.')
  End if;
End;
/
```

Students Table

```
SNUM  SNAME  STANDING  MAJOR  GPA  MAJORGPA
****  *****  ********  *****  ***  ********
121   Liz      2       FIN   2.8     3.2
```

Comment: Can you give details regarding your students table?

Comment: Edited with some more details!

Comment: It's really not clear what question you're asking. Other than the missing semi-colon after the `dbms_output` call your program works. The logic is slightly confused you need to tweak the condition so that it matches the rule you're trying to enforce.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following changes :

1) you can use

AFTER UPDATE OF GPA ON students

2) you can compare like

```
IF :new.gpa < :old.gpa  THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('Old GPA is lower than previous GPA by at least 1 
       point.')
    END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps and this code to get the desired results.

```
Create or Replace TRIGGER AUGPA
  after update on students
  for each row 
begin
  if :new.gpa - :old.gpa  >= 1 
    THEN
      dbms_output.put_line ('Old GPA is lower than current GPA by at least 1 point.');
  End if;
End;
/

set serveroutput on;
update Students set gpa  = gpa + 1 ;
commit;
```

Comment: Question: If I update Liz's GPA by changing it to 2.0, it should not output a message. Is there any way to do that in the trigger? Only gpa's that are lower than 1 or more have a message.

Comment: you mean something like `if :new.gpa > :old.gpa and  :new.gpa != 2.0` ?

Comment: So if Liz'a GPA changes to 2.0 there should be no output. Since 2.8 - 2.0 = 0.8. And 0.8 is less than 1. If I added another user whose GPA was 3.0 and their new GPA was 2.0 then there should be an output because it decreases by 1. Thank you!

Comment: @Lizzie : Modified now take a look.

Comment: I'm getting an error at line/col 5/3. PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: The symbol "l" was substituted for "END" to continue.

Comment: @Lizzie : don't know how are u compiling it & where you have inserted a pipe symbol. It is compiling fine for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160645/discussion-between-lizzie-and-kaushik-nayak).

Comment: Just realized there is an error. If the :newgpa = 3.5 and :old.gpa = 3.1 the trigger will still run because the difference is less than one.

Answer (score 0):

Your operation is backwards. 
Lets use the following new.gpa = 1.5, old.gpa = 3. So the gpa has fallen by by 1.5 so the message should be issued. The message will not be issued: the code is "If new.gpa - old.gpa >= 1 then message ..." However 1.5 - 3 = -1.5 which is not >- 1. Change to "If old.gpa - new.gpa >= 1".

@Anand suggests is not good as it would generate the message if the gpa fell to 2.9 from 3; just a .1 drop